# MobileFirst Java SQL Adapter deployment failes with "null"

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm following the [Java SQL Adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/comment-page-1/) tutorial from IBM MobileFirst Platform.
The RSSAdapter is deployed successfully, but the UserAdapter deployment fails.

The errors:

> [ERROR   ] Preparation to deploy adapter 'UserAdapter' failed.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

And

> Adapter deployment failed: null

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLcSl.jpg
[image]

Comment: Did you follow all the steps for setting up the JDBC driver? Please include server logs and server.xml, maybe even your adapter java code.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fail is not setting up the data source.
After configuring server.xml file, the adapter deployed succesful

Comment: Can you mark this (your) answer as the correct answer since you figured out the solution already.